# Grails/Gradle Plugin for Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin, gradle, grails-2.0

I'm trying to use the grails-gradle plugin with grails version 2.0.  Here is my build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo url: "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT",
                  "org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.0.0"
    }

    grailsVersion="2.0.0"
}

apply plugin: "grails"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo url: "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.grails:grails:2.0.0",
            "org.grails:grails-core:2.0.0",
            "org.grails:grails-crud:2.0.0",
            "org.grails:grails-datastore-core:1.0.2.RELEASE",
            "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:1.0.2.RELEASE",
            "org.grails:grails-hibernate:2.0.0",
            "org.grails:grails-logging:2.0.0"
}
```

The dependencies at the bottom of the script are different than the original "1.3.4" located [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin).  When I use this script to create a grails project with `gradle grails-init` it works correctly, creating the project.  When I try to use `gradle grails-run-app` I receive the following errors:

```
~>gradle grails-run-app
:grails-run-app
| Configuring classpath
| Error log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver).
| Error log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
| Error log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
| Compiling 38 source files

| Compiling 8 source files.....
| Error Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [hibernate]
- Plugin: hibernate
   - Dependencies:
       ! dataSource (Required: 2.0 > *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
       - i18n (Required: 2.0 > *, Found: 2.0.0) 
       - core (Required: 2.0 > *, Found: 2.0.0) 
       - domainClass (Required: 2.0 > *, Found: 2.0.0)
```

I'm assuming that this means I'm missing a dependency, but I have no idea what dependency.  It looks like `hibernate` is the culprit, but I have included the grails hibernate jar above.  The list of jars between the two versions of grails are different, so I'm not sure which should be included (or maybe there isn't one and this will not work).  The list of dependencies can be see [here](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/).

Any help resolving these errors would be much appreciated.

Using: 
gradle 1.0, milestone-7 & grails 2.0.0

**NOTE**: the dependency `"org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT"` is a local copy of the tip revision from [github](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle / Grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027313/gradle-grails-application)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. This is a very helpful thread, to answer your question, you need to add "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.0.1" on compile, it solved the problem on my machine.

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work for "grails-run-app".  It will init and assemble a project, but I can't run it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a few dependencies... Check [Gradle / Grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027313/gradle-grails-application/12170741#12170741) for a complete example of how to do this.

Hope this helps!