# Gradle / Grails application

Tags: grails, gradle

I have been trying to configure Gradle to manage a Grails project for a couple of hours with no success. The suggestions I've found here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the Internet didn't work for me.

Could you please give me up-to-date directions on how to configure a Gradle+Grails project? Ideally it should relate to the current versions of Grails (2.1.0) and Gradle (1.1).

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin

I've experimented with it and grails 1.3.5 a while ago and it was quite buggy but it seems to be much more smooth now handling 2.x versions and up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### BuildScript

```
import org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsTask

buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenRepo name: "grails", url: 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' 
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT"
        }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo name: "grails", url: 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' 
}
version = "1.0"
grailsVersion = "2.1.0"
apply plugin: "grails"
dependencies {
    ['dependencies', 'resources', 'core', 'hibernate', 'plugin-datasource', 'plugin-domain-class', 'plugin-tomcat', 'plugin-services'].each { plugin ->
        compile "org.grails:grails-$plugin:2.1.0"
    }
    bootstrap "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6"
}

GRAILS_TASK_PREFIX = "grails-"
if (name.startsWith(GRAILS_TASK_PREFIX)) {
    project.task(name, type: GrailsTask) {
        command "${name - GRAILS_TASK_PREFIX}"
    }
}
```

### Initialize

Then you can do `gradle init` to initialize the project structure

### Commands

Use `gradle grails-[grails script]` to execute your grails commands. For example: `gradle grails-run-app` is equivalent to `grails run-app`

Hope this helps!

### Update

This seems to work for Grails 2.3.2:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
        }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo'  }
}
version = "1.0"
apply plugin: "grails"
apply plugin: 'idea'
grails {
  grailsVersion = "2.3.2"
}
dependencies {
    ['dependencies', 'core', 'spring', 'web', 'plugin-datasource', 'plugin-domain-class', 'plugin-controllers', 'plugin-services'].each { plugin ->
        compile "org.grails:grails-$plugin:2.3.2"
    }
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.42'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.3'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.173'
    bootstrap "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9"
}
```

A note, throws Exception when generating Grails wrapper, but `gradle init` seems to initialize the project structure properly otherwise. And, `gradle grails-run-app` seems to work fine too.

Comment: this fails for me. When I change bootstrap "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.7" to 1.8.6 it works...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for grails commands with arguments such as `gradle grails-create-domain-class x.y.Z`

Comment: @C.Ross, gradle grails-create-domain-class -PgrailsArgs=mydomain.Person

Comment: Would this be true for Grails plugins as well? I've been trying to use it for the liquibase migrations plugin, e.g. but `./gradlew grails-dbm-list-locks` responds with `Task 'grails-dbm-list-locks' not found in root project 'aps-metrics'.`