# How do I know what webserver gradle / grails is using?

Tags: grails, gradle

This thread: [Gradle / Grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027313/gradle-grails-application/12170741#12170741) describes how to set up the grails plugin for gradle.

The command `gradle grails-run-app` tries to start the grails application on port 8080.  What webserver is gradle using here?

Does it have an embedded one?  If so how can I access / configure it?

Comment: Accept an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just shelling out to the same thing that Grails would have done without Gradle, as if you had run `grails run-app`. That depends on which server plugin you have installed. By default it's http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat, but you can switch to http://grails.org/plugin/jetty by changing the values in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: but where is this Tomcat server exactly?  Say I want to see its access logs, how do I do that?

Comment: It runs embedded - both Tomcat and Jetty are very easy to run in-memory without a "real" install. Logs end up under the `target` directory

Answer (score 3):

Gradle is nothing but a build and config tool like maven. When you use it with Grails app the dependencies are managed by it as it happens when maven is used.

When you use `gradle grails-run-app` it does nothing more other than running `grails run-app` from its own context. The same embedded Tomcat server is used by default.

Comment: Where is this tomcat server embedded exactly?  Can i see it on my filesystem?

Comment: You should be able to see it per project in `USER_HOME` [.grails\<version>\projects\<YourProject>\tomcat\..] for the resources used in the server. As a whole the server runs in-memory.